# Как включить подсветку синтаксиса css в PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Поставил PhpStorm и не работает подсветка синтаксиса, и более того даже файл похоже не определяется как `css`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить что-бы была подсветка синтаксиса и вообще файл определялся как `css`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, имя `style.css` ассоциировано с типом файла **TEXT**. Откройте `File | Settings | Editor | File Types | Text` и проверьте, нет ли `style.css` среди **Registered patterns**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того, чтобы ассоциировать ваш файл с типом **Cascading Style Sheet**, достаточно убрать его имя из списка паттернов, зарегистрированных для типа **Text**

Comment: Либо может быть удаленна ассоциация css файла с css синтаксисом, это исправляется в той же вкладке, только надо выбрать тип файла  css и добавить к registered patterns строчку '*.css'